# Why does Clang complain an "initializer element is not a compile-time constant" for a local compound literal?

Tags: c, macros, clang, compound-literals

With the following code,

```
#define REINT(T, X) (union {__typeof__(X) x; T t;}){X}.t

int f2i(float x) {
  return REINT(int, x);
}

float i2f(int x) {
  return REINT(float, x);
}

float f2i2f(float x) {
  return REINT(float, REINT(int, x));
}
```

Clang complains about `f2i2f` that an "initializer element is not a compile-time constant". This seems odd because compound literals "have automatic storage duration associated with
the enclosing block" (6.5.2.5p5), and the elements in the initializer list for such objects don't have to be compile-time constants.

Comment: I suspect it's because you can'tuse a nested compound literal in the initializer.

Comment: gcc doesn't seem to mind even with `-pedantic`.

Comment: Have you search the clang bug list? https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues

Comment: @Barmar I found a bug report with a very similar use case (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/25689). Interesting because it is quite an old bug still not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments under the question, it was mentioned that this is a known bug, and *"it is quite an old bug still not fixed"*. So until it's fixed, you'll have to work around it.

The simplest code I could find that triggers the bug is

```
int x = 3;
struct { __typeof__((int){x}) y; };
```

The bug is triggered when:

- a compound literal with a non-constant initializer
- is used in the argument to `__typeof__`
- in the declaration of a member variable in either a `struct` or a `union`

When the `REINT` macro is used in the `f2i` and `i2f` functions, it doesn't trigger the bug because argument `X` is not a compound literal. `X` in those functions is a variable with a primitive type.

But in the `f2i2f` function, the argument `X` passed to the *outer* invocation of `REINT` contains a compound literal. And that compound literal is part of the argument to a `__typeof__` that is used in the definition of the *outer* `union`.

So the workaround is to avoid nesting the `REINT` macro. For example, `f2i2f` can be implemented as follows:

```
float f2i2f(float x) {
    int temp = REINT(int, x);
    return REINT(float, temp);
}
```